# Fuzzing with SPIKE - generic_send_tcp error

Tags: security, fuzzing, kali-linux

I know SPIKE is already outdated, but I have to do it in SPIKE.

I am trying to do this `generic_send_tcp 0.0.0.0 8080 check_post.spk 0 0`
bu I get that `generic_send_tcp: undefined symbol: s_string`
Should I add sth or remove. I will add that two weeks ago it worked perfectly.

My script looks like this:

```
s_string("POST");
s_string(" "); 
s_string("/"); 
s_string(" ");
s_string("HTTP/1.1");
s_string("\r\n");
s_string("Content-Length:");
s_blocksize_string("block1", 5);
s_string("\r\n");
s_string("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
s_string("\r\n");
s_block_start("block1");
s_string("login=");
s_string_variable("a");
s_string("&password=");
s_string_variable("a"); 
s_block_end("block1");
s_string("\r\n");
```

Comment: Do you include `spike.h`? Is `s_string` present in `spike.h`?

Comment: @nevilad It is present in spike.h. I don't include, but when I did I got an error about permission. It worked perfectly in this way two weeks ago.

Comment: `s_string` is an external function, it should have a declaration in this source file or some of the included files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I know it's simple but 'sudo apt-get install spike' fixed the issue for me. Thanks